# Big o in probability vs. little o in probability

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

The sequence $b_n$ is at most of order $n^{-1/2}$ in probability, denoted by $b_n=O_p(n^{-1/2})$.
Now, when $n \to \infty$, can we get $b_n=o_p(n^{-1/2})$?

Comment: No, only the reverse holds

Answer (score 1):

This does not hold in general, here's a counterexample:

Let $X \sim N(0,1)$ and let $b_n = n^{-1/2}X$.

Then $b_n / n^{-1/2} =X$ is stochastically bounded so that $b_n = O_p(n^{-1/2}).$

But $X = b_n / n^{-1/2} \not\to 0 $ in probability, so that $b_n \ne o_p(n^{-1/2})$